# How can a user with read-only access to Git make a pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm working on some collaborative projects with my coworkers. We're starting to adopt Git.

I have a repository in Bitbucket, and I gave read-only access to one of my associates. After he made ​​his corrections and contributions to the project, how can he make a "pull request" if his user profile is read-only? How can he upload his branches to the repository?

The second, taking a user profile writing, as we can prevent its branches merge repository to master without having gone through a "pull request" and that the administrator has decided to accept your request.

Comment: Fernando, please note that this website is English-only. I've attempted to translate your question, but I couldn't understand Google Translate's translation of the last paragraph. Please try to edit that yourself. *Fernando, por favor tenga en cuenta que este sitio web es de sólo Inglés. He tratado de traducir su pregunta, pero yo no podía entender de Google Translate Traducción del último párrafo. Por favor, intenta modificar usted mismo.*

Comment: Thanks
I'll try to translate my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your coworker only has read access to the repo, then he'll need to fork the repo, clone it down, make his changes, push them back up, and then make a pull request from his repo to yours.

Obviously you'll have your reasons for restricting permissions, but if he has read-write access to the repo, he simply needs to make a branch on that repo, push it, and he can then issue the pull request.

[Here is some additional info from bitbucket on working with pull requests](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-pull-requests-for-code-review/)

Comment: On github the in-browser editor automatically does this when you edit a file in a repo that you don't have write access to. Does bitbucket do the same thing?

Comment: @bdsl Bitbucket will do the same thing.
 See [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/edit-online-351764818.html)

Comment: [Updated link](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-edit-and-commit-to-source-files/#Add,edit,andcommittosourcefiles-Editfilesonline) for the comment above.